# Trying to use ReadLine.Skip(5) keep getting error -- Conversion from type '<SkipIterator>d__31(Of Char)' to type 'String' is not valid.'

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I am trying to read numbers from a text file
example: 01 02 03 04 05 06
I want to start the read from line 15 but when I use skip(15) it causes conversion error.

```
    Dim PbArrData_PrintTickets(FileLength)
    Dim CurrentPRP = New String(7) {}

    Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/Database/Filters/" & FilterFile)

        'Store the Entire File's Contents into the Array

        Do While sr.Peek() >= 0

            PbArrData_PrintTickets(ipbp) = sr.ReadLine.Skip(15) ' <-- Everytime I try to add Skip() it causes the error?

            CurrentPRP(6) = Mid(PbArrData_PrintTickets(ipbp), 16, 2)
            CurrentPRP(5) = Mid(PbArrData_PrintTickets(ipbp), 13, 2)
            CurrentPRP(4) = Mid(PbArrData_PrintTickets(ipbp), 10, 2)
            CurrentPRP(3) = Mid(PbArrData_PrintTickets(ipbp), 7, 2)
            CurrentPRP(2) = Mid(PbArrData_PrintTickets(ipbp), 4, 2)
            CurrentPRP(1) = Mid(PbArrData_PrintTickets(ipbp), 1, 2)
```

Comment: What is the data type of `PbArrData_PrintTickets`?

Comment: Skip bypasses a specified number of elements in a collection..ReadLine returns a string so your Skip is skipping 15 characters.

Comment: You need a conversion or two to get from the result of `Skip` to a `String`.  You'll definitely want to add `ToArray()` to the end there (converting the sequence returned by `Skip` to an array), and I think you also need to wrap the whole thing in `New String(...)` i.e. `PbArrData_PrintTickets(ipbp) = New String(sr.ReadLine.Skip(15).ToArray())`.

Comment: All of which assumes that the `Skip` is doing what you want by taking the line and then skipping the first 15 characters.